# is there a way to force layout mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using 1 template to add or edit my model.

When I introduce a modal window this 1 template reuse breaks down.  I would prefer to force bootstrap to use a mode xs, sm when inside the modal window.

## Problem

[image: bootstrap modal window problem]

## Appearance Desired in Modal Window

[image: Appearance I want inside the modal window]

## Question:

Does anyone know how I can achieve this effect without having 2 separate views?

A solution that let's me specify on the modal window container:

```
.force-sm
.force-xs
```

I am using angularjs so if it cannot be done with 100% css approach maybe a dynamic approach.

For now my work around will be to increase the width of the modal window.

Comment: Please post some HTML of yours (mainly the markup for the modal window)

Comment: @PeteTNT assume it only uses col-md-* definition.  Your viewing it on desktop so bootstrap will use render the lg definitions (which there are none so it will use the col-md-  definition which are defined.  There are no col-xs, col-sm definitions defined.  I just want it to stack when the container is small.

Answer (score 2):

**I love this question!** And frankly it surprises me that it's not baked right into Bootstrap, because once I thought about it for a bit, it was quite simple and versatile... Create custom descendant classes (`modal-col-*`)  which apply only when descended from `.modal-body`, and define their width like Bootstrap's column widths are defined. So:

```
.modal-body .modal-col-12{width:100%} /* only applies when wrapped in .modal-body */
```

You can extrapolate on this and create a bunch of similar classes with appropriate % widths, and add them to the element, knowing it will only fire when needed, like so:

```
<div class="col-md-6 modal-col-12">Something</div>
<div class="col-md-6 modal-col-8">Something else</div>
```

**Here is an example: http://www.bootply.com/g7fM6h7Mfx**

Comment: that is a potential solution and it is simple - thanks.  It does  require adding additional markup and would be redundant if the template already defined col-sm/xs specific layout. The ideal solution wouldn't require changing the markup and would cancel the CURRENT bootstrap media query @media (min-width: xx) for all elements in the modal and apply the forced media query settings to take effect.  After thinking more about it seems a angularjs directive would be the only way to create that ideal scenario.  Will put in the backlog.  Thanks!

Comment: I am surprised. Since you said you wanted something you could specify on the modal container (i.e. .force-sm), sounded like you were going to modify the markup anyways... but if you want to keep your markup untouched, I think you're right about needing something more advanced.

Comment: You got me even more curious though, and realized you can just do this: .modal-body > .col-md-6{width:100%}. Not a single change to markup required, even what you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, instead of editing my existing answer, I think this one is equally valid, based on preferences... You could also totally override Bootstrap's classes using the same principle, but applied to their stock classes:

```
.modal-body > .col-md-6{width:100%}
```

Again, you can extrapolate that to do the same for any class you want to override.

**Example here: http://www.bootply.com/jRVeZwjAfb**

NOTE: I say this is based on personal preference, because I don't like overwriting/overriding Bootstrap's existing classes, and prefer to add custom classes so they can be turned on/off at will without affecting layout elsewhere. But this seems to more precisely match what you want.

Comment: suffers from the same "DRY" problem.  Requires redefining layout when the template could already have  col-sm/xs definition .

Comment: Sure, it *could*, but it does't. Seems to me this achieves your end goal with 100% CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little off to add yet another answer, but this question piqued my interest so much that I went and created a library to achieve this: https://github.com/shawntaylor/bootstrap-force-device

Essentially, add the custom CSS to your project, and add `.force-xs` (or sm, md, lg) to a parent div (in this case, a modal body) to force the enclosed grid to behave as if it's on the declared device:

```
<div class="modal-body force-sm">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-7">.col-lg-4 .col-sm-6 .col-xs-7</div>      
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">col-lg-4 .col-sm-6 .col-xs-5</div>
...
```

[**Sample with lots of examples**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/838533/LiveSites/bootstrap-force-device/index.html)